# Select Query to get the timezone for DB2

Tags: sql, db2

I want to know the timezone of my DB2 server.

Plese suggest me a query to get UTC or CET or so.
Thanks.

Comment: is this [tag:sql-server] or [tag:db2]? The title and the content of the post suggest the former, while the tags suggest the latter.

Comment: What is it you want this information for?  In at least some versions of DB2, the "current" time for stuff like `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` will be evaluated in the timezone of the current connected session - you can get times from the future (admittedly, this is largely due to some versions not supporting storing the offset in the timestamp).  This is why one of the common recommendations for webservers/dbservers is to set them to UTC, regardless of physical location (getting a 'local' timestamp is actually a display-layer job).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to get the timezone, you need to query the special register CURRENT TIMEZONE. For more information please visit:

```
db2 VALUES CURRENT TIMEZONE

db2 "select CURRENT TIMEZONE from sysibm.sysdummy1"
```

Comment: it gives some code as 20000 i want the display name like UTC or CET. Can i get it somehow?

Comment: @Romi The value returned is a duration offset from UTC, in HHMMSS.  You could, fairly easily, modify this into something like "GMT+2" or "GMT-7", but if you want a timezone name (CET, PDT, etc) you'd have to create a table with a list of timezone offsets and names and look up the name.

Comment: @IanBjorhovde, because of Daylight saving time changes and rule changes there are multiple variants...